# Am I required to report my Multiple Sclerosis to the DMV?

Tags: united-states, traffic, medical, alabama

I was recently told that in every state, you must report to the DMV if you have MS.  However, I can not find anything to verify this.  Is this correct?

Specifically, I live in Alabama, but would be curious if the general claim is true.

Comment: Is the MS disabling enough for you to either have or qualify for DP license plates?

Comment: I am very lucky and my MS is not physically disabling in any way.

Answer (score 5):

Alabama has published an [administrative interpretation](http://www.alabamaadministrativecode.state.al.us/docs/alea/760-X-20.pdf) of [§32-6-7, §32-6-7.1, Code of Ala](https://law.justia.com/codes/alabama/2017/title-32/chapter-7/). 1975 regarding medical standards for driver licensing. This allows them to take medical conditions into consideration in denying, not renewing, or restricting a license. This includes, for example, the ability to consider the fact that a person has high blood pressure. The review standard basically says that if they review a person and determine that there is a significant medical impairment, they can restrict driving privileges. 760-X-20-.10 addresses MS and related conditions, which basically restates that. There is nothing in the statutes that requires a person to report a specific medical condition of theirs. A doctor could, however, report that a patient is not fit to drive, which could trigger a DMV evaluation. P. 13 of the state [Driver License Manual](http://dps.alabama.gov/Documents/Manuals/DriverLicenseManual.pdf) sums it up saying

> When  it  appears  that  you  have  some  physical  or  mental 
>   impairment   which  might  affect  your  driving  ability,  you  may 
>   be  required  to  furnish  a   statement  from  a  doctor  showing 
>   your  medical  history  and  present  condition as it pertains to your
>   driving ability.

This does not translate into a requirement to self-report medical conditions that potentially affect ability to drive. It is highly unlikely that any state singles out MS, but every state has the potential to restrict driving if a person is medically unsafe to drive.